# Error-timeout after 30000ms in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to open a `pop up (panel)` using ADD button but I am getting time out even with setting- `settimeout-30000/600000/1200000` and also using `waitforpagetoload` function with the same time as I mentioned for `settimeout`.
Anyone help ?

Comment: I think you should be try with `waitForVisible`

Answer (score 4):

Change configuration in Selenium IDE. Click on menu, Options->options->In general Tab give 60,000 or above in Default Timeout Textbox.

Answer (score 1):

As you said waitforpagetoload is not working for you.
Try using `pause` command, that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are having is that the script doesn't recognize the popup and also the ide get stuck. if that is the case,

This happened to me several times. This is happening because a popup can't be located by the script. You have to use a locate the frame of the popup and get it's id.

try using:-  WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

(iframe should be the id of the frame you take from the ide)

hope this would help.

Comment: it's been 3 years but I have the same problem here. In my case, I want to pop-up a gmail signin, but selenium gives me "timed out 30000". could you explain more detail about your answer? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Slow down the speed of your test to run. Probably Selenium doesn't have enough time to catch the element